# How to Add :committed Days to :levels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, text, integer

How can we only use `:committed` days when calculating what level a habit is on?

Each of the `:levels` has a different amount of days that must pass before the habit moves onto the next level (as shown in the **model** below).

Currently `t.text :committed` has no significance to `t.integer :levels`. Lets change that! Thanks in advance for your expertise =]

**form**

```html
<%= f.label "Committed to:" %>&nbsp;
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :committed, Date::DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s %>
```

```html
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 validates :action, presence: true
 serialize :committed, Array

 scope :missed, -> { where(missed: 1) }
 scope :nonmissed, -> { where(missed: 0) }

 def levels
   n_days = Integer(Date.today - date_started)

  case n_days   
   when 0..9
     1
   when 10..24
     2
   when 25..44
     3
   when 45..69
     4
   when 70..99
     5
   else
     "Mastery"
  end
 end
end
```

**controller**

```html
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
   @habits = Habit.all.order("date_started DESC")
   @missed_habits = current_user.habits.missed
   @nonmissed_habits = current_user.habits.nonmissed
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @habit = current_user.habits.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @habit = current_user.habits.build(habit_params)
    if @habit.save
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @habit.update(habit_params)
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @habit.destroy
    redirect_to habits_url
  end

  private
    def set_habit
      @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @habit = current_user.habits.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to habits_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this habit" if @habit.nil?
    end

    def habit_params
      params.require(:habit).permit(:missed, :left, :levels, :date_started, :trigger, :action, :target, :positive, :negative, :committed => [])
    end
end
```

Comment: Please help here (50 bounty): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596406/how-to-make-level-change-based-on-committed-days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming committed is a field containing an array of day names (e.g. `['Monday', 'Friday']`, the following should work:

```
committed_wdays = committed..map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day) }
n_days = (date_started..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday }
```

Comment: Now the level remains 1 regardless of the :date_started or :committed days. Thanks so much for your help! And I removed one of the periods before map bc it was causing an error.

Comment: Ah yes - that was a typo.  Are you saying it didn't work?  Have you tested it using irb or rails console?  It certainly works.  Is this a dynamic attribute or are you storing levels in your database?

Comment: I tested it in development. `t.integer  "levels"` is in the database, but I only broke down the :levels in rb. When I look at the habits index the levels are now all listed as 1 instead of being at their appopriate level based upon the ruby logic. I just don't understand it. It should work. I pushed it up to Github to give you a better look at it if you need it: https://github.com/RallyWithGalli/ruletoday

Comment: `levels` is simply a dynamic getter method - it will have no effect on the database.  You need to create an appropriate filter to set the levels attribute before the record is saved.  You need to [read this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).  Please mark the answer as accepted as it provides the solution you required and this is a separate issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks silvabox for your time. I continued the conversation over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519683/how-to-set-a-filter-for-levels-attribute-before-record-is-saved. Not completely sure how your link helps, but thanks for trying to educate.

Comment: Sorry - I was on a packed train with poor internet connection and I posted the wrong link.  [try this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) which talks about ActiveRecord callbacks which is what you need - not filters - filters are for controllers!  I was having a bad day :o)  The answer given to your new post is correct.  You only need one level/levels column, you just need to set its value with a callback.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me with the new link. England congestion probably isn't as bad as Florida traffic ;) For some reason the answer given in the new post isn't working. I tried various callbacks, rewording of :level, and adding "private", but no luck here.