# How to Use Callback to Set :Level Value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, filter, integer

I'm creating a habit tracking app.

When a User creates a habit he will put in its `:date_started` and which days he is `:committed` to doing the habit.

Then after X amount of `:committed` days the habit moves onto the following `:levels` until eventually it hits "mastery" (days in the levels are broken down in the **model** below).

I already figured out `date_started`.

Now how can we use committed days, instead of just any day, to calculate what level a habit is on?

`:levels` is a dynamic getter method, which currently has no effect on the database.

I was told I need an appropriate callback to set the `:levels` attribute before the record is saved, but I don't know how.

Will you accept this challenge?

**form**

```html
<%= f.label "Committed to:" %>&nbsp;
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :committed, Date::DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s %>
```

```html
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 validates :action, presence: true
 serialize :committed, Array

 scope :missed, -> { where(missed: 1) }
 scope :nonmissed, -> { where(missed: 0) }

 def levels
   committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day) }
  n_days = (date_started..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday }

  case n_days   
   when 0..9
     1
   when 10..24
     2
   when 25..44
     3
   when 45..69
     4
   when 70..99
     5
   else
     "Mastery"
  end
 end
end
```

**controller**

```html
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
   @habits = Habit.all.order("date_started DESC")
   @missed_habits = current_user.habits.missed
   @nonmissed_habits = current_user.habits.nonmissed
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @habit = current_user.habits.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @habit = current_user.habits.build(habit_params)
    if @habit.save
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @habit.update(habit_params)
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @habit.destroy
    redirect_to habits_url
  end

  private
    def set_habit
      @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @habit = current_user.habits.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to habits_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this habit" if @habit.nil?
    end

    def habit_params
      params.require(:habit).permit(:missed, :left, :level, :date_started, :trigger, :action, :target, :positive, :negative, :committed => [])
    end
end
```

**Github**: https://github.com/RallyWithGalli/ruletoday

Thanks in advance for your expertise =]

Comment: add `level` column in your table then in the model, add: `before_filter :set_level` and add method: `def set_level; self.level = levels; end`

Comment: I already have t.integer :levels as a column for habits. Are you saying add another column called t.integer :level or t.string :level? I did both plus added your code and got this error: undefined method before_filter. I then tried adding before_filter to the controller, but that didn't work either.

Comment: `before_save` not `before_filter` sorry for the error... also rename your `levels` column to `level`..

Comment: Thanks for the help Zakwan. I tried various callbacks, rewording of :level, and adding "private", plus more but still no luck. The :level now isn't changing regardless of what I put for the :date_started or :committed.

Comment: @Zakwan I continued the conversation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596406/how-to-make-level-change-based-on-committed-days