# How to Make :level Change Based on :committed Days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a habit tracking app.

When a User creates a habit he will put in its `:date_started` and which days he is `:committed` to doing the habit.

Then after X amount of `:committed` days from the `:date_started` the habit moves onto the succeeding `:level` (amount of days per level are broken down in the **model** below).

In other words, how can we use `:committed` days, instead of just any day, to calculate what `:level` a habit is on?

From what I know my current code should work, but for some reason the `:level` isn't changing regardless of what a User puts for the `:date_started` or `:committed`.

**20150130201715_create_habits.rb**

```html
class CreateHabits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :habits do |t|
      t.integer :missed
      t.datetime :left
      t.integer :level
      t.text :committed
      t.datetime :date_started
      t.string :trigger
      t.string :action
      t.string :target
      t.string :positive
      t.string :negative
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :habits, :users
    add_index :habits, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

**habit.rb**

```html
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 before_save :set_level
 validates :action, presence: true
 serialize :committed, Array

 scope :missed, -> { where(missed: 1) }
 scope :nonmissed, -> { where(missed: 0) }

 def levels
   committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day) }
  n_days = (date_started..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday }

  case n_days   
   when 0..9
     1
   when 10..24
     2
   when 25..44
     3
   when 45..69
     4
   when 70..99
     5
   else
     "Mastery"
  end
 end

private
 def set_level
  self.level = levels
 end 
end
```

**habits_controller.rb**

```html
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]


  def index
    @habits = Habit.all.order("date_started DESC")
    @habits = current_user.habits
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @habit = current_user.habits.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @habit = current_user.habits.build(habit_params)
    if  @habit.save
        redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully created.'
    else
        @feed_items = []
        render 'pages/home'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @habit.update(habit_params)
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @habit.destroy
    redirect_to habits_url
  end

  private
    def set_habit
      @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @habit = current_user.habits.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to habits_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this habit" if @habit.nil?
    end

    def habit_params
      params.require(:habit).permit(:missed, :left, :level, :date_started, :trigger, :action, :target, :positive, :negative, :committed => [])
    end
end
```

**habit _form**

```html
<%= f.label "Committed to:" %>&nbsp;
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :committed, Date::DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s %>
```

**habit index**

```html
<td><%= habit.levels %></td>
<td><%= habit.committed.map { |d| d.titleize[0,3] }.join ', ' %></td>
<b><%= habit.date_started.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %></b>
```

**Github**: https://github.com/RallyWithGalli/ruletoday

Thanks in advance for your expertise =]

Comment: I think @keyzee 's answer should work with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your only problem is that you're storing the day names in lowercase in the `committed` field, and then trying to match them with `Date::DAYNAMES`, which has them in title case.  Otherwise, the logic seems sound.

This should work:

```
committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize) }
n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you can do this depending on your business logic.  For example if you were unlocking certain privileges with each level you would want to handle it differently than if the level was simply to display a UI feature.  Either way you would add a levels table that will hold the name of your level in a :name attribute.  Then you would have a habit_level table that would be a join with the foreign key of the habit and the foreign key for the level.  When ever you are updating the days you run a check to see if the days are of a certain number, and if they are, you create a record in the join table for the corresponding level and habit.

Comment: Can you include some code? I'm having a hard time implementing your suggestions. Thanks ruby_newbie!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is `committed`? I see:

`t.text :committed`

and

`committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day) }`

That doesn't really make sense, I'm not sure how that works for you. It looks like you're storing multiple day names, if that's the case you should use an array of some sort (either strings or integers). Then you can set `n_days` to simply `committed.length`.

I would change that column to `t.string :committed, array: true, default: []` or `t.integer :committed, array: true, default: []`.

Comment: He uses `serialize` for `committed` attribute.. that makes sense

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Thanks!  That said, I would still prefer arrays.